# Apply css only for variable products - WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I wonder if there is a way to apply style for only variable products in WooCommerce. I need it because one of my buttons i custom styled and it goes out of place when there is variable product.

Sorry, here is https://prntscr.com/kuo735 the button and here is the URL persoonlijktelefoonhoesje.nl/product/… and here is the button that it's out of place -> https://prntscr.com/kuo8a9 and the variable product http://persoonlijktelefoonhoesje.nl/product/geometric-unicorn-telefoonhoesje/

Comment: You need to show the HTML of your variable product here and point out the button.

Comment: Sorry, here is http://prntscr.com/kuo735 the button and here is the URL http://persoonlijktelefoonhoesje.nl/product/iphone-7-bamboo-hout-telefoonhoesje-ontwerpen/ and here is the button that it's out of place -> http://prntscr.com/kuo8a9 and the variable product http://persoonlijktelefoonhoesje.nl/product/geometric-unicorn-telefoonhoesje/

Comment: When you ask on stackoverflow adding links is not the best practice. Instead of it, it would be better to past the code in your question.

Comment: i believe that it is better to add links, i always do it when i ask question. It is easier for someone that wants to help to just check the code, and find the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the product is variable it's container has a `product-type-variable` class. So, in your case CSS of the button for vairable product will looks like this:

```
.product-type-variable .entry-summary{

}
```

Make sure that only one element on your page has class `entry-summary`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i haven't noticed that it has this class .product-type-variable. That helped a lot.